# Integration tests in spring boot application with spring cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-test

I have an spring-boot application that uses config server. 
In project I have a bootstrap.yml:

```
spring:
 cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${CLOUD_CONFIG_URI:http://localhost:8888}
      failFast: true
      enabled: ??
```

and I can pass actual config for server location through parameter. That's ok.

With this configuration I don't know how to disable this in integration tests. My tests load this configuration and want to communicate with config server. I know that I can pass `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` but it's not a solution (I want to right click in IDE and run test without additional configuration per each test method).

Any idea?

Comment: have tried using spring-profile for your integration tests?

Comment: Could you please suggest how to use profiles here? Ideal solution would be to use 'test' profile for enabled option (enabled if active profile is different than 'test'), but how to do this ?

Comment: You can use @Profile("test") at class level and add spring.profiles.active=test,dev in application.yml or appliation.properties file and use -Dspring.profiles.active=test while running the code..

Comment: You are right, but how this can solve my issue? I have test profile enabled with tests. How to use this profile to disable config server ?

Comment: you can mention disabling your config server in your test profile.

Comment: No, Spring loads properties from config server before local files, therefore disable it in test profile / test properties doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a late answer but for the people that join from any search engines here is my solution:

The @Profile("test") annotation above your integration test class is correct. To get this really working is adding two extra configuration files to your normal resources folder, not the test resources folder.

1. Add "application-test.yml"
2. Add "bootstrap-test.yml"

In your bootstrap-test.yml add the following:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        config:
          enabled: false
```

With this configuration you can put all of your needed configuration options in the application-test.yml and the bootstrap-test.yml will disabled spring cloud config.

Comment: So, how I do if I must get data from repository to use on integrationTest?

Comment: @Augusto This is an approach in case your integration test would like to avoid connecting to the config server